# Snowflake Kafka Connector, topic2table mapping, getting insufficient error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-schema

[image][image][image]"**snowflake.topic2table.map": "uat.product.topic:UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021**" has been configured in the connector. I am getting below error. However. below grants were already given.

```
GRANT READ,WRITE ON FUTURE STAGES IN SCHEMA "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA" TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";

GRANT WRITE ON STAGE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021" TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";
```

But still getting below error

```
 **10126** [2021-12-16 11:19:20,700] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1236)

**10117** [2021-12-16 11:19:20,651] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1082)
```

Please help

**Below is the error which has made the snowflake-distributed-connector go down:**

```
  10072 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Detail: Failed to upload file to Snowflake Stage though JDBC
  10073 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: SQL access control error: 
  10074 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Insufficient privileges to operate on table stage 'UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021'
  10075 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:126)
  10076 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:66)
  10077 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:434)
  10078 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:338)
  10079 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:482)
  10080 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.parseCommandInGS(SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.java:1180)
  10081 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.parseCommand(SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.java:843)
  10082 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.<init>(SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.java:819)
  10083 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.getFileTransferAgent(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:187)
  10084 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.uploadStreamInternal(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:867)
  10085 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.uploadStream(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:772)
  10086 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.moveToTableStage(SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.java:509)
  10087 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.moveToTableStage(SnowflakeSinkServiceV1.java:884)
  10088 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.checkStatus(SnowflakeSinkServiceV1.java:823)
  10089 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.lambda$startCleaner$0(SnowflakeSinkServiceV1.java:478)
  10090 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  10091 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  10092 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  10093 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  10094 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  10095 [com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeErrors.getException(SnowflakeErrors.java:284), com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeErrors.getException(SnowflakeErrors.java:266), com.        snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeErrors.getException(SnowflakeErrors.java:256), com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.moveToTableStage(SnowflakeConnection        ServiceV1.java:516), com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.moveToTableStage(SnowflakeSinkServiceV1.java:884), com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowfla        keSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.checkStatus(SnowflakeSinkServiceV1.java:823), com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1$ServiceContext.lambda$startCleaner$0(SnowflakeSinkServic        eV1.java:478), java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511), java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker        (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)] (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Sno        wflakeSinkServiceV1:81)
  10096 [2021-12-16 11:19:11,319] INFO
  10097 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] uploadWithoutConnection successful for stageName:SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021, filePath:file_stream_dem        o_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021/2/2653366_2653661_1639653551128.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeInternalStage:63)
  10098 [2021-12-16 11:19:11,320] INFO
  10099 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2, flush pipe: file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_TOP        IC_15DEC2021/2/2653366_2653661_1639653551128.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10100 [2021-12-16 11:19:15,828] INFO
  10101 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] uploadWithoutConnection successful for stageName:SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021, filePath:file_stream_dem        o_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021/5/2653598_2653914_1639653555629.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeInternalStage:63)
  10102 [2021-12-16 11:19:15,828] INFO
  10103 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5, flush pipe: file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_TOP        IC_15DEC2021/5/2653598_2653914_1639653555629.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10104 [2021-12-16 11:19:17,994] INFO
  10105 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2, ingest files: [file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_        TOPIC_15DEC2021/2/2653366_2653661_1639653551128.json.gz] (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10106 [2021-12-16 11:19:17,994] INFO Sending Request UUID - 3050a7a3-afd8-4ff4-a86d-427c6d3724c1 (net.snowflake.ingest.SimpleIngestManager:554)
  10107 [2021-12-16 11:19:17,994] INFO Created Insert Request : https://abc0000.XX-XXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443/v1/data/pipes/KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distri        buted_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2/insertFiles?requestId=3050a7a3-afd8-4ff4-a86d-427c6d3724c1&showSkippedFiles=false  (net.snowflake.ingest.connection.RequestBuilder:504)
  10108 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,092] INFO In retryRequest for service unavailability with statusCode:200 and uri:/v1/data/pipes/KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1        770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2/insertFiles?requestId=3050a7a3-afd8-4ff4-a86d-427c6d3724c1&showSkippedFiles=false (net.snowflake.ingest.utils.HttpUtil:118)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5, ingest files: [file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_        TOPIC_15DEC2021/5/2653598_2653914_1639653555629.json.gz] (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10112 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,092] INFO Sending Request UUID - 24c5542c-75fc-4265-957f-e9c2d167ba7a (net.snowflake.ingest.SimpleIngestManager:554)
  10113 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,092] INFO Created Insert Request : https://abc0000.XX-XXX-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/v1/data/pipes/KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distri        buted_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5/insertFiles?requestId=24c5542c-75fc-4265-957f-e9c2d167ba7a&showSkippedFiles=false  (net.snowflake.ingest.connection.RequestBuilder:504)
  10114 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,222] INFO In retryRequest for service unavailability with statusCode:200 and uri:/v1/data/pipes/KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA.SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1        770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5/insertFiles?requestId=24c5542c-75fc-4265-957f-e9c2d167ba7a&showSkippedFiles=false (net.snowflake.ingest.utils.HttpUtil:118)
  10115 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,222] INFO Attempting to unmarshall insert response - HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json, Date: Thu, 16 Dec 2021 11:19:18 GMT, Expect-CT: enforc        e, max-age=3600, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000, Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Country: United States, X-Frame-Options: deny, X-XSS-Protection        : : 1; mode=block, Content-Length: 88, Connection: keep-alive] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 88,Chunked: false]}} (net.snowflake.ingest.SimpleIngestManager:5        62)
  10116 [2021-12-16 11:19:18,223] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=file-stream-demo-distributed-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1245: {uat.product.topic-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=265366        2, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, uat.product.topic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2653774, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, uat.product.topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2657653, leaderEpoch=null, me        tadata=''}, uat.product.topic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2665892, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, uat.product.topic-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2665734, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, uat.product        .topic-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2653915, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:346)
  **10117** [2021-12-16 11:19:20,651] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoo        rdinator:1082)
  10118 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,652] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:225)
  10119 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,652] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:553)
  10120 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,661] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Successfully joined group with generation 16 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:5        04)
  10121 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,661] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Joined group at generation 16 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1        -41cfdb70-f9b9-443b-bf18-4d6c77b5951c', leaderUrl='http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/', offset=422, connectorIds=[file-stream-demo-distributed], taskIds=[file-stream-demo-distributed-0], revokedConnectorI        ds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1681)
  10122 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,661] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1089        )
  10123 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,661] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Current config state offset 419 is behind group assignment 422, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.        connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1150)
  10124 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,700] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 422 (org.apache.kafka.connec        t.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1154)
  10125 [2021-12-16 11:19:20,700] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 422 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.Distributed        Herder:1208)
  **10126** [2021-12-16 11:19:20,700] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1236)
  10127 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,662] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoo        rdinator:1082)
  10128 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,662] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:225)
  10129 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,662] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:553)
  10130 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,665] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Successfully joined group with generation 17 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:5        04)
  10131 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,665] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Joined group at generation 17 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1        -41cfdb70-f9b9-443b-bf18-4d6c77b5951c', leaderUrl='http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/', offset=422, connectorIds=[file-stream-demo-distributed], taskIds=[file-stream-demo-distributed-0], revokedConnectorI        ds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1681)
  10132 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,666] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 422 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.Distributed        Herder:1208)
  10133 [2021-12-16 11:19:23,666] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1236)
  10134 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,376] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67)
  10135 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,377] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:327)
  10136 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,388] INFO Stopped http_XX.XX.XX.XXX8083@464ede1f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:380)
  10137 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,389] INFO node0 Stopped scavenging (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:158)
  10138 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,395] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:344)
  10139 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,395] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:676)
 10140 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,396] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Stopping connectors and tasks that are still assigned to this worker. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distrib        uted.DistributedHerder:650)
  10141 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,399] INFO Stopping connector file-stream-demo-distributed (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:387)
  10142 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,399] INFO Scheduled shutdown for WorkerConnector{id=file-stream-demo-distributed} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:249)
  10143 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,399] INFO Stopping task file-stream-demo-distributed-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:836)
  10144 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,399] INFO
  10145 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkConnector:stop (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:121)
  10146 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,401] INFO
  10147 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:close (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:209)
  10148 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,401] INFO
  10149 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10150 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,401] INFO
  10151 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10152 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10153 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_2: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10154 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10155 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_3: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10156 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10157 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10158 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10159 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_3: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10160 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10161 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_0: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10162 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10163 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10164 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10165 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_0: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10166 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10167 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_1: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10168 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,402] INFO
  10169 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10170 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10171 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_1: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10172 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10173 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_4: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10174 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10175 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10176 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10177 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_4: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10178 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10179 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5: cleaner terminated (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.Snowflak        eSinkServiceV1:63)
  10180 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10181 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] IngestService Closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:32)
  10182 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,403] INFO
  10183 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_PIPE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021_5: service closed (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSin        kServiceV1:63)
  10184 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,404] INFO
  10185 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:close. Time: 0 seconds (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:214)
  10186 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,404] INFO
  10187 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:stop (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:167)
  10188 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,404] INFO
  10189 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10190 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10191 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,405] INFO
  10192 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10193 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10194 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,405] INFO
  10195 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10196 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10197 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,409] INFO
  10198 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10199 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10200 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,411] INFO Completed shutdown for WorkerConnector{id=file-stream-demo-distributed} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:269)
  10201 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,413] INFO
  10202 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10203 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10204 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,413] INFO
  10205 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Cleaner terminated by an interrupt:
  10206 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] sleep interrupted (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:63)
  10207 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,413] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-file-stream-demo-distributed-0, groupId=connect-file-stream-demo-distributed] Revoke previously assigned partitions uat.produc        t.topic-2, uat.product.topic-3, uat.product.topic-0, uat.product.topic-1, uat.product.topic-4, uat.product.topic-5 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:307)
  10208 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN
  10209 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]: sink not initialized or closed before preCommit (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:256)
  10210 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] INFO
  10211 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:close (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:209)
  10212 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 2, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10213 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 3, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10214 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 0, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10215 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 1, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10216 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 4, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10217 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] WARN Failed to close sink service for Topic: uat.product.topic, Partition: 5, sink service hasn't been initialized (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkS        erviceV1:81)
  10218 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] INFO
  10219 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:close. Time: 0 seconds (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:214)
10220 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,414] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-file-stream-demo-distributed-0, groupId=connect-file-stream-demo-distributed] Member connector-consumer-file-stream-demo-distr        ibuted-0-4d8276fe-e3e4-4b89-843f-b2c595f17e94 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 10.28.18.248:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients        .consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1005)
  10221 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,433] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Member connect-1-41cfdb70-f9b9-443b-bf18-4d6c77b5951c sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator XX.XX.XX.XXX:90        92 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1005)
  10222 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,433] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Close timed out with 1 pending requests to coordinator, terminating client connections (org.apache.kafka.client        s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:986)
  10223 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,434] INFO Stopping KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-status (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:167)
  10224 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,435] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-2] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
  10225 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,438] INFO Stopped KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-status (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:193)
  10226 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,438] INFO Closing KafkaConfigBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:285)
  10227 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,438] INFO Stopping KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:167)
  10228 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,444] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-3] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
  10229 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO Stopped KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:193)
  10230 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO Closed KafkaConfigBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:287)
  10231 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:209)
  10232 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO Stopping KafkaOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore:134)
  10233 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO Stopping KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:167)
  10234 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,448] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
  10235 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,451] INFO Stopped KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:193)
  10236 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,451] INFO Stopped KafkaOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore:136)
  10237 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,451] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:230)
  10238 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,452] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:299)
  10239 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,453] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:696)
  10240 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,453] INFO Kafka Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:72)error
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow grants to the database and schema the following grants need to be done:

```
grant usage on database kafka_db to role kafka_connector_role_1;
grant usage on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1;
grant create table on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1;
grant create stage on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1;
grant create pipe on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1
```

Has all these grants been done?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Yes these grants were given. But getting the error of Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing.

Comment: How can I restrict the heartbeat failure as this is causing all the distributed connector to get disconnect for Master. And in worker nodes [2021-12-16 11:19:20,497] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1082). Due to this other 2 worker nodes are also disconnecting

Comment: [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] uploadWithoutConnection successful for stageName:SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021, filePath:file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299/UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021/4/2948067_2948377_1639701793509.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeInternalStage:63)
[2021-12-17 00:43:13,759] INFO

Comment: Still the error is coming even after giving the suitable grants

Comment: You last log snippet shows upload was successful. Are you still getting the same SQL access control error?

Comment: 10072 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Detail: Failed to upload file to Snowflake Stage though JDBC
  10073 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: SQL access control error: 
  10074 [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Insufficient privileges to operate on table stage 'UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021'10095

Comment: 10135 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,377] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:327)
  10136 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,388] INFO Stopped http_XX.XX.XX.XXX8083@464ede1f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:380)
  10137 [2021-12-16 11:19:24,389] INFO node0 Stopped scavenging (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:158)

Comment: Sergui, getting this error [2021-12-20 15:34:03,614] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] searched 5 files in ingest report, found 1 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:63)
[2021-12-20 15:34:03,758] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] purge 1 files from stage: SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:63)
[2021-12-20 15:34:04,077] WARN Cleaner encountered an exception class com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeKafkaConnectorException:

Comment: I see the log reports stage name as **SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021** while your grant is on **SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021**. Are you sure you haven't set the stage name in as per log vs the grant where you used **""**? I am referring to [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)

Comment: GRANT READ, WRITE ON STAGE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021" 
TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";

grant create pipe on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1;

GRANT READ,WRITE ON FUTURE STAGES IN SCHEMA "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA" TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";

Comment: I think you missed my point: these 2 statements: **CREATE STAGE "Testing_stage";
CREATE STAGE "TESTING_STAGE";** are creating 2 different stages because I enclosed them in **""**, basically I used 2 different identifiers. Is that your case as well?

Comment: Can you do a **SHOW STAGES;** and see what the stage name is exactly?

Comment: Adding two images in main problem statement for the reference

Comment: So I missed mentioning that **SHOW STAGES** should be run under Kafka user/role. Anyway, the log shows a stage name that has a mix of capitals and small letters, while your grant is for a stage with only CAPITAL letters in name so my assumption is that you're having 2 different stages used. The "SHOW STAGES" should confirm if this is the case and show the real stage name.

Comment: Please check the images enclosed with the SHOW STAGES which was executed under KAFKA_DB and a screen shot of the stages for this table which is all in capital letters.

Comment: Added images enclosed with the both table giving access, which do don't exists. As only one name SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021 exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240289/discussion-between-austin-jackson-and-sergiu).