# Snowflake Kafka Distributer Connector Geeting error in the connect.log

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, kafka-consumer-api, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

```
[2021-12-20 15:34:03,614] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] searched 5 files in ingest report, found 1 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:63)
[2021-12-20 15:34:03,758] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] purge 1 files from stage: SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_file_stream_demo_distributed_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:63)
[2021-12-20 15:34:04,077] WARN Cleaner encountered an exception class com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeKafkaConnectorException:
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to upload file
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Error Code: 2003
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Detail: Failed to upload file to Snowflake Stage though JDBC
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: SQL access control error:
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Insufficient privileges to operate on table stage 'UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021'
```

However necessary rights were provided to the stage including future stage

Comment: The error comes when Kafka connector tries to purge a file from the stage. It seems the role used doesn't have write access on that stage. In your case check the reply from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378006/snowflake-kafka-connector-topic2table-mapping-getting-insufficient-error/70379211?noredirect=1#comment124488444_70379211)

Comment: GRANT READ, WRITE ON STAGE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021" 
TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";

grant create pipe on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1;

GRANT READ,WRITE ON FUTURE STAGES IN SCHEMA "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA" TO ROLE "KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1";

Comment: I think you missed my point: these 2 statements: **CREATE STAGE "Testing_stage";
CREATE STAGE "TESTING_STAGE";** are creating 2 different stages because I enclosed them in **""**, basically I used 2 different identifiers. Is that your case as well?

Comment: grant create stage on schema kafka_schema to role kafka_connector_role_1; was also given Sergiu. And this is the stage from stages :SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_FILE_STREAM_DEMO_DISTRIBUTED_1770328299_STAGE_UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021